# To update a property in object in Array with React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have an input field which is written in a child component 
and its inside return function

```
const EditSectionComponent = ({
    editCaption,
    editName,
}) => {
    const {name,caption} = details;

    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        className="imageNameDetails"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => editName(e.target)}
        />  
    )
}
```

and in parent Component, it's like

```js
  const onEditClick = id => {
    const selectedAsset = All.find(i => i.id === id);
    setDetails(selectedAsset);
}

const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

const editName = target => {
    setDetails({ ...details, [name]: target.value })
};
```

Initial page load I can see both caption and name in the text field, but I am not able to change its value

It's not updating the UI. Is the right way to reflect the newly edited text in the input field

Comment: You need to pass editName function to child component, so child component can use editName function to update parent state and then pass back to child component

Comment: @Colin i do. have everything  like you told . jus didnt post it in question

Comment: maybe setDetails({ ...details, name: target.value }) ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted valid code. How are you passing these props? 'details' is undefined in your example.

Comment: @BEVR1337 i had shared the onEditClickLink function, it do set the setDetails state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure to destructure the `details` from props in `EditSectionComponent`.
- In your parent, the initial state i.e. `details` is defined as an array. It need to be an object.
- Also while doing `setDetails`, you need to specify the key. (not a dynamic name in your case)

**Updated code is here:**

```js
const EditSectionComponent = ({
    editCaption,
    editName,
    details,
}) => {
    const {name,caption} = details;

    return (
        <input
        type="text"
        className="imageNameDetails"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => editName(e.target)}
        />  
    )
}
```

```js
const [details, setDetails] = useState({name: '', caption: ''});

const editName = target => {
    setDetails(prev => ({...prev, name: target.value}))
};
```